# How do i point my domain to wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, redirects, url-rewriting, blog, multiple-domains

I would like to know that if we have our WordPress blog like: `http://koolkabin.wordpress.com`  and our domain like: `http://www.outsourcingnepal.com` then

Can we make it like working and posting all contents in `http://koolkabin.wordpress.com` and showing the contents in our domain i.e `http://www.outsourcingnepal.com`

For more clarification:

if user enters `http://www.outsourcingnepal.com` or `http://koolkabin.wordpress.com` in their browser address bar then both should show contents from `http://koolkabin.wordpress.com`

but one more thing when user visit the website from `http://www.outsourcingnepal.com` the URL should remain `http://www.outsourcingnepal.com` not `http://koolkabin.wordpress.com`

Comment: Links in posts are `rel="nofollow"`; ten links to your sites in your question does not clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On WordPress.com, you can use a custom domain for your blog, such as example.com, instead of the default address you get when you sign up, like example.wordpress.com. This is called Domain Mapping, and it’s a paid upgrade. Mapping a domain you already own costs $12 per domain, per blog, per year.

Instructions:

- [Map an Existing Domain | Wordpress.com](http://en.support.wordpress.com/domain-mapping/map-existing-domain/)

Important note:

> Using the Domain Mapping Upgrade requires you to change your domain’s “Name Servers”. If you don’t know how to do this, we suggest you contact your domain’s registrar before proceeding. You will not be able to start mapping your domain to your blog before you complete this stage.